# orthographic projection in raytracing

Tags: shader, vulkan, raytracing

i have a working perspective projection based ray tracing renderer in vulkan, i want to convert it into an orthographic projection, i tried replacing the perspective projection matrix by orthographic projection matrix and taking the ray origin as the pixel coordinates, but it seems to have not working, clearly something is wrong.

```
    uint randSeed = initRand(gl_LaunchIDEXT.x + gl_LaunchIDEXT.y * gl_LaunchSizeEXT.x, ubo.frameID, 16);

    //vec4 origin           = ubo.viewInverse * vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); //for perpective
    vec4 origin         = ubo.viewInverse * vec4(gl_LaunchIDEXT.x, gl_LaunchIDEXT.y, 0.0,  1.0); //for ortho

    // ---- [Apply jitter to anti alias] ---- 
    vec2 jitter         = vec2(nextRand(randSeed), nextRand(randSeed)) - 0.5;
    //vec4 target           = ubo.projInverse * vec4((gl_LaunchIDEXT.xy + jitter) / gl_LaunchSizeEXT.xy * 2.0 - 1.0, 0.0, 1.0); //for perpective
    vec4 target = ubo.orthoInverse * vec4((gl_LaunchIDEXT.xy + jitter) / gl_LaunchSizeEXT.xy * 2.0 - 1.0, 0.0, 1.0); //for ortho
    vec4 direction = ubo.viewInverse * vec4(normalize(target.xyz), 0.0);
```

i am calculating the orthographic matrix using glm::ortho function,
i also tried calculating using the below code, but i am not getting the desired result -

```
// set the OpenGL orthographic projection matrix
void glOrtho(
    in float b, in float t, in float l, in float r,
    in float n, in float f,
    inout mat4 M)
{
    // set OpenGL perspective projection matrix
    M[0][0] = 2 / (r - l);
    M[0][1] = 0;
    M[0][2] = 0;
    M[0][3] = 0;

    M[1][0] = 0;
    M[1][1] = 2 / (t - b);
    M[1][2] = 0;
    M[1][3] = 0;

    M[2][0] = 0;
    M[2][1] = 0;
    M[2][2] = -2 / (f - n);
    M[2][3] = 0;

    M[3][0] = -(r + l) / (r - l);
    M[3][1] = -(t + b) / (t - b);
    M[3][2] = -(f + n) / (f - n);
    M[3][3] = 1;
}
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Please post a complete example, including some actual details of what "not working" means.

Comment: Show the value for the matrix and for the inverse. Ideally make it the trivial case of just looking down the z axis. Should become obvious what's the problem. I mean, it is orthogonal. All the `direction`s should be the orthogonal, i.e. same.